# I tried to print string line by line.

Tags: javascript

```
var animal = new Array("s","b","c","k","h","g"); 
var animalString =''; 
for(var m=0; m<animal.length; m++){ 
    //console.log(m)
    animalString+= animal[m] +"\n";
    console.log(animalString);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem please add description

Comment: you have only put the snippets of code but not the error or any problem. how people will solve you problem

Comment: i want just like s  b  c  k  h  in  line by line

Comment: @Satyam: Maybe you want this - http://jsfiddle.net/9p9dx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is the following:

```
var animal = ["s","b","c","k","h","g"];
for (var x = 0; x < animal.length; x++) {
    console.log(animal[x]);
}
```

There's no need to try and put it into a string and print that to the console. `console.log()` has a carriage return within the console anyway.

Comment: thanks Luxelin frnd work fine

Answer (score 0):

only like an advise use join

```
var animal = new Array("s","b","c","k","h","g"); 
var animalString = animal.join("\n");

    //console.log(m)
    console.log(animalString);
```

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rSvhf/)</kbd>**

Comment: Why first set a variable to `''` and then use `+=`? You might as well assign it the value you want to start with. Heck, if that's the only use of the variable, you might as well inline it, too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but i think you are looking for this:

```
 var animal = new Array("s","b","c","k","h","g"); 
 var animalString = animal.join().replace(/\,/, '<br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var animal = new Array("s","b","c","k","h","g"); 
var animalString =''; 
for(var m=0; m<animal.length; m++){  
    console.log(animal[m]);
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p9dx/)

You don't need to any string manipulation OR use `+=` here, Because `animal` is an array object and as you said you only want to string  `like s b c k h in line by line`.
So, the for loop execute all array items one-by-one.